# An error has occurred. See error log for more details. org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.File cannot be cast to org.eclipse.core.resources.IProject

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, selenium3

Getting an error while viewing the properties of the folders. Earlier it was working fine I don't know what the problem is.

I removed the dependencies and added again but still getting the same error.

There is no code for that!

Expected Output will be:

> The location of the folder will come inside a Pop-up with few options.

Comment: _See error log for more details._ The log file is located at `<worspace>/.metadata/.log`. Probably a plug-in that you have installed into Eclipse causing this. But without the details from the log this is only guessing. Please give step-by-step instructions and an example how to reproduce this issue.

Comment: Just created a new Maven-Project and added all the dependencies in it and it works for me. There are no proper steps for that issue. I guess something was missing on the pom.xml [But not sure]